# Flex 3: ChangeWatcher on a [Bindable] variable not working

Tags: apache-flex, variables, monitoring

I have a Number variable, named isConflict, whose value is passed in from a parent.  I would like to put a ChangeWatcher on this item so that a function named changeBGColor will run whenever the value is changed.  Within my creationComplete function of init, i have the following:

```
var isConflictWatch:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(changeBGColor, this, "isConflictChain");
```

However, the function is not being called when the value of isConflict changes.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use a straight ChangeWatcher since you're not really binding anything:

```
var watcher:ChangeWatcher = ChangeWatcher.watch(this, ["isConflict"], onIsConflictChanged);
```